# What does the asterisk on Thread ID means?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am debugging an Android Project and notice that there are asterisks on some of the Thread ID. What is it for?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daemon threads are shown with an asterisk (*). This will be one of the following:

- running - executing application code
- sleeping - called Thread.sleep()
- monitor - waiting to acquire a monitor lock
- wait - in
         Object.wait()
- native - executing native code
- vmwait - waiting on a
         VM resource
- zombie - thread is in the process of dying
- init - thread
         is initializing (you shouldn't see this)

you can read more about [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html)